# Running out of memory when using Dask arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I need to perform some computations on a tensor larger than memory, but first I need to construct it from `NumPy` arrays (parts) that fit in memory.

I'm computing these `NumPy` arrays, then converting them to `Dask` arrays, and putting them on a `list`. My final tensor is a particular concatenation of these arrays. The problem is that, depending on the number of parts, I'm not even able to reach the line of code where the concatenation happens.

For example, using parts of shape `(30, 40, 40, 40, 40)`, so of around `614 MB`, with `16 GB` of RAM (usually `10` free), just trying to compute `20` parts is enough to run out of memory.

I can see how the computation of each new tensor gets slower and how the available RAM gets lower and lower until the process gets killed. If I compute `10` parts, I can see my available `RAM` dropping from `10 GB` to `5.2`. If I try to compute `20` parts, the process gets killed.

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def compute_part():
    array = np.random.random((30, 40, 40, 40, 40)) # 614 MB
    return da.from_array(array)

def construct_tensor(nparts):
    list_of_parts = []
    for part in range(nparts):
        part_as_da_array = compute_part()
        list_of_parts.append(part_as_da_array)
    # Below, the concatenation should happen

construct_tensor(20) # This is enough for the process to not finish
```

Is there a way to make a better use of the available memory? Dask automatically creates `chunks` of sizes `(15, 20, 20, 20, 20)`, and I've also tried rechunking the arrays so each piece is smaller, but I've seen no improvement. I currently see little difference when I use `Dask` arrays instead of `NumPy` ones in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for dask to "reduce" the size of an array you present to it already in memory. No chunking will help you. **If** your data fit into memory, maybe you wouldn't need Dask at all.

Instead, you need to load/create data as required in each chunk. For your simple example, you could achieve this by replacing your `compute_part` with `da.random.random`, which is lazy in exactly this way (doesn't use any memory until each chunk is actually used).

I appreciate that random numbers are probably not your actual use case. If the pieces really need to be in memory first, you might end up using [`da.from_delayed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_delayed), or running through your chunk creation step for each chunk first, writing to a data store like zarr which supports chunk-wise writes.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I thought there was some spilling to disk done. I'm not using random numbers but a more complex computation, however, I got some ideas from your answer.